# Next js change path name based on local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-router

In my next.js project, I want to change the URL based on the locals

This is my default URL for `en` language

`http://localhost:3000/en/privacy-policy`

Now if I switch the language `en` to `fr` then I want to change the url like this

`http://localhost:3000/fr/politique-de-confidentialite`

Here I will be on the same page will change the content depending on locals `en` or `fr`

Page will be same just will change the url `privacy-policy` to `politique-de-confidentialite` based on `en` or `fr`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your architecture design and how you translating the content either  you using `packages` to translate the content or you fetching the content from database depending on current language.
In general, you can make the page's `slug` dynamic, like the following folder structure;

```
-> app // app router folder
  --> [locals] // dynamic language slug
  --> page.js
     ---> [pages] // dynamic page slug (name) for locals
     ---> page.js
```

So, when you change the language you can translate, get from file, or from database the current path and redirect to it like this `http://localhost:3000/${locals}/${pages}` (`http://localhost:3000/en/privacy-policy` to `http://localhost:3000/fr/politique-de-confidentialite`).

For more information and detail you can refer to this examples https://github.com/PhraseApp-Blog/next-i18next-demo-2023 or/and
https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/tree/master/examples